# Where is the meteor package source code put in mac?

Tags: macos, meteor, package

I added meteor packages in terminal.

Now I want to see the source code of a package in local, I know I can find it on github, but is there a directory in finder that I can open in Atom to see the source code files?

Thanks.

Comment: In Ubuntu, it is ` ~/.meteor/packages`, give it a try

Comment: ~ is home folder ' cd ~/.meteor/`

Comment: It in ~/.meteor/packages (cf http://goo.gl/53nrE6)

Comment: And just for reference, in Windows10, it is typically located at ` C:/Users/UserName/AppData/Local/.meteor/packages`

Answer (score 0):

For OSX, it is in `~/.meteor/packages/package_name/version_number`.

Inside that directory you will find that the package has been built for different platforms. e.g. `os`, `web.browser`, `web.cordova`.